# Alternative to using overlay: hidden to stretch a div to fill gaps and keep children div the same size as parent

Tags: html, css

I have a standard header layout (logo on the left, menu on the right) with a "streching" search input div on the right that takes up the unused center space when focused. The solution I could get working was adding `width: inherit` and `overflow: hidden` to the search's div to get it to fill the rest of the empty space. The problem is the search results are to be displayed underneath the search input as the same width.

My first thought was to place the results outside of the search div but then I don't know how I can get the search results div to match the same width and position of the search input div.

```js
$(function(){
 
 $('.field').focus(function(){
  $('.search').addClass('focused');
  $('.search-results').show();
 });
 $('.field').blur(function(){
  $('.search').removeClass('focused');
  $('.search-results').hide();
 });
 
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, section {
  max-width: 72em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.logo, .menu {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  height: 75px;
  line-height: 75px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 250px;
  /*
   * Overflow: hidden is the root of one problem and a
   * solution to another filling the extra space.
   */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.search .field {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.search.focused {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
}

.search-results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background: salmon;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div class="logo">Dynamic Width</div>
 <div class="menu">Dynamic Width</div>
 <div class="search">
  <form>
   <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
  <div class="search-results"></div>
 </div>
</header>
<section>
 <p>This content should not be moved.</p>
</section>
```

Here's what I am hoping to achieve when input is focused.

[image]
I am well aware content does not go outside overflow:hidden boundaries. The question is how to emulate overflow:hidden to take up remaining space and child divs fit inside said area. Any suggestions on how I might achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `overflow: hidden;` if you wanna show something out of the boundary?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I am using overflow hidden to make the div take up the unused center space, but that creates the problem of not being able to show search results outside the bounty, like I said in my article and asked for other suggestions.

Comment: Dude, I checked the code in JSBin too. You are trying to achieve something awesome, but you are not doing it the right way.

Comment: Your title is a pretty decent summary of your question so I don't see why Praveen would need to read far past it to understand what you're doing. If you're going to use overflow: hidden, don't complain about content being clipped - because that's exactly what you're telling the element to do.

Comment: Here let me quote myself. `The solution I could get working was adding width: inherit and overflow: hidden to the search's div to get it to fill the rest of the empty space. The problem is the search results are to be displayed underneath the search input as the same width. `

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use `flexbox` here :)

Comment: @l3fty You need to employ a different method bro. Will try in a different way and get you an output. Behold.

Comment: @l3fty YOU CANNOT USE WIDTH INHERIT. Browser definitely doesn't know how to handle it.

Comment: @l3fty I have already started working http://jsbin.com/zoluhinavo/edit?html,output, dude, I am fast. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar THERE CHANGED IT TO AUTO

Comment: It is not good idea to use `float` to keep elements in same line. Instead use `flex` and all things will be easy.

Comment: @Kejt I Would love to see a Flexbox example if you wouldn't mind. That's one thing I am terrible at. *Edit, it actually looks like flexbox isn't even supported at IE11. I'll need better support than that.

Comment: @l3fty Done... Check it out. Might not be perfect. But... `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flexbox solution in header

https://codepen.io/kejt/pen/jwrzZm

your `searchbox` has `flex-grow:1`, your `header` has `display: flex;`

Comment: @l3fty here you go :)

Comment: Thanks but how does this work with the "unfocused" state where the search should be to the right side? Then when you focus the input, it'll stretch to what you have here. Also, is Flexbox even supported in IE? Seems like it still very much unsupported.

Comment: here you go https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox, I will modify codepen for your usecase

Comment: Yeah I took a look at that too, so IE isn't supported at all. IE11 is still very much buggy.

Comment: what do you want to achieve when not focused?

Comment: You can take a look at my test case snippet on the original post. Might be easier to spot if the window is expanded.

Comment: Hrmm, that might actually work. I'll have to play around with it as the actual search div isn't stretching and this is a bare test case. The real layout has more than just the input field stretching. I guess i could use a wrap for that though. Thanks a lot , I'll play around with it.

Comment: awesome! good luck, flexbox is really cool, once you start using it you don't want to go back :D

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the header to `position:absolute`, adding some padding to the body to offset the size of the header (fixed to `75px` by `.menu` and `.logo`), removing the fixed height on `.search` to allow it to take up as much height as it needs to show results too and finally only setting `overflow-x:hidden` on `.search`

```js
$(function(){
 
 $('.field').focus(function(){
  $('.search').addClass('focused');
  $('.search-results').show();
 });
 $('.field').blur(function(){
  $('.search').removeClass('focused');
  $('.search-results').hide();
 });
 
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding-top: 75px;
}

header, section {
  max-width: 72em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 25px 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.logo, .menu {
  float: left;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.menu {
  width: 250px;
  float: right;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  line-height: 75px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 250px;
  /*
   * Overflow: hidden is the root of one problem and a
   * solution to another filling the extra space.
   */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.search .field {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.search.focused {
  width: auto;
  float: none;
}

.search-results {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: salmon;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <div class="logo">Dynamic Width</div>
 <div class="menu">Dynamic Width</div>
 <div class="search">
  <form>
   <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
  <div class="search-results"></div>
 </div>
</header>
<section>
 <p>This content should not be moved.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is closer to a fix I can use/need. I will play around with this and see if I can get it to work as this is just test case created from a much more complicated layout. I am not exactly sure how well `position: absolute;` is going to play with the sticky footer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Flex box** solution. I hope helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.field').focus(function(){
       $('.search').addClass('focused');
       $('.menu').removeClass('grow');
   });
   $('.field').focusout(function(){
       $('.search').removeClass('focused');
       $('.menu').addClass('grow');
   });
});
```

```css
header{
  height:100px;
  display: flex;
  }
  .logo{width:120px;}
  .menu{  background-color: orange;}
  .menu.grow {flex-grow: 1;}
  .field{width: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
  .search{background-color: #ddd;}
  .search.focused{
    flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 
 <div class="menu grow">Dynamic Width</div>
 <div class="search">
  <form>
   <input class="field" placeholder="Search" type="text">
  </form>
  <div class="search-results"></div>
 </div>
  <div class="logo">Dynamic Width</div>
</header>
```